# find the minimum sum of matrix (n x n) that select only one in each row and column

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, dynamic-programming, graph-algorithm

this is another algorithms problem related to dynamic programming

Here is the problem :

find the minimum sum of the given matrix such that select one in each row and column

For example :

3 4 2

8 9 1

7 9 5

the minimum one : 4 + 1 + 7

I think the solution is network flow (max flow/min cut) but I think it shouldn't be as hard as it is

My solution: seperate to n list[column], column1, column2 ... column n

then start point (S) -> column1 -> column2 -> ... -> column n -> (E) end point
and implement max flow/min cut

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?

Comment: @BoltClock ok I'm now editing

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is the [Assignment Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) which can be considered a special case of minimum weight perfect matching in graphs. The classic way to solve the Assignment Problem is to use the [Hungarian Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm).

Comment: I also developed my algorithm which is similar to Hungarian Algorithm but it is slower than it. However, it is mine algorithm :) I'll show you. Thanks for your help